# After maven project import in IDEA 14, some classes are not recognized as java class

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

After maven project import in IDEA 14, some classes are not recognized as java class. [image: class]. 
And the project in which those classes are not marked as source(in blue)[image: project].

I am not so familiar with project, so could someone tell me is this a some error in pom files or this can be valid case.? If this is error , how to fix this problem .

I would like to mention that re import of project did not help (I also have deleted .idea folder ), so I think the problem is connected with wrong configs in pom.xml. This is a multi module project and there are different maven profiles in project.

Thanks for any ideas and helps ))

Comment: Which jdk do you use?

Comment: How did you import the project?  Did you also remember to update the Maven sources in the project (there's a refresh button for Maven in its tab)?

Comment: thanks for response, 1)JDK is 6. 2)Yes I have updated maven project(auto import is enabled!)

Comment: Are there Java source files outside the conventional `/src/main/java` dir? If so, is that specified as a source root in the `pom.xml` file? You can follow the answer @VojtechRuzicka gave but that will be something every dev will have to do. If you make sure your pom defines all source directories (which ist should anyway for maven builds to work in the first place), you won't need to do this IDEA specific thing.

Comment: @JesseWebb thanks,  yes the classes are in src/main/java, but you are right i do not want to do some IDEA specific thing, So i think problem in pom.xml

Comment: Can you update your question with your project dir structure and your `pom.xml` contents which may be relevant? Right now we are left guessing at what possibly could be the problem.

Comment: Sorry I cannot post code from project (I work in company) and also there are more than 100 maven modules in whole project. I will try do more research(if I found problem I will post answer ). Thank you very much for help..

Answer (score 3):

If you right click on a directory and click

> Mark Directory As -> Sources Root

Intellij Idea will recognize files inside as Java files

[image]

Comment: Thank you for help, this fix first problem, but after that there is other classes which are not recognized(missing dependencies for other class e.g @Test ),

Comment: I think I need to find the root of problem, why IDEA does not recognize after import.

Comment: If you build your project with maven does it build or are there build errors?

Comment: there are no build errors, but in that module I have integration test and they throw some ClassNotFoundException, So I think there is problem with classpath.

Answer (score 2):

By default, Maven expects all source code to live in `/src/main/java` (or `/src/test/java`). You can have code that lives elsewhere but then you have to tell Maven about this unconventional paths in your `pom.xml` file.

My guess is that you have source that lives outside of these dirs and is not referenced in the `pom.xml` file. If this is true, I would guess your command-line maven builds are broken too.

[This SO question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3354785/346561) explains how to tell maven about sources outside of the standard dirs. It looks something like this:

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/custom</sourceDirectory>
</build>
```

IntelliJ IDEA will recognize this setting in your pom.xml file and set the appropriate directory as a source folder within your project.

IMO though, it is not a good idea to stray away from Maven conventions unless you really have to. The more conventions you follow, the less complicated your `pom` will be. it also helps new devs pick up work on your project quickly if they already have experience with other Maven projects.

Comment: thanks , but this is not my case , source file are in /src/main/java. probably the problem in maven profiles because for this module there is separate profile.